# Display problem when changing of screen kivy

Tags: python, kivy, raspberry-pi3

I'm developing a kivy app with several screens. My problem is during the transition from a screen to another : when the app is running, a sort of "merge" between the two screens appears during 2 or 3 seconds (see screenshot below).

I'm guessing it is due to the CPU load of my app, but is there a solution to wait for a page to be completely load to change screen ?
(i'm running my app on an Raspberry pi 3 with a tactil screen)

thank you in advance !

## Screen 1

[image: screen 1]

## Screen 2

[image: screen 2]

EDIT : A first solution could be to multithread my kivy app. I don't know yet how, but [this](https://github.com/kivy/kivy/wiki/Working-with-Python-threads-inside-a-Kivy-application) could be helpful

Comment: Try to multithread it

Comment: Are you using `ScreenManager`? If so, try `NoTransition`.

Comment: Yes I'm using `ScreenManager` and already use the `NoTransition` animation (I had several problems with the `FadeTransition`.

Martin, I have no idea on how to multithread a kivy app, i will do some researches